# return all users posts ASC excepts last 7 ones left join sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return all my users posts except the last 7 ones. MySql.

**The pattern would be something like this:**

```
 SELECT *
 FROM posts
 WHERE id_post < (SELECT * FROM posts min(id_post) WHERE id_user=4 
 ORDER BY id_post DESC LIMIT 7)
 ORDER id_post ASC
```

**If I Left Join with the Users table**

```
SELECT q.*,q.id_post as id
FROM posts q
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id_user=q.id_user
WHERE p.id_user=4
AND q.id_post < (SELECT min(rel.id_post) as min_id_post
                    FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT p.*
                        FROM posts p
                        WHERE p.id_user=4
                        ORDER BY p.date  DESC 
                        LIMIT 7
                    ) rel )
```

I retrieve the results by this last query, but it has so many subqueries...
Is it a subquery needed to achive what I want? Is there a shorter version?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: its not a difficult question... the question is basically how to return all my users posts except the last 7 ones. Maybe my tried is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an Outer Join (in fact the `WHERE p.id_user=4` turns it into an Inner Join anyway).

You should be able to use a LIMIT to skip the first 7 rows:

```
SELECT q.*,q.id_post as id
FROM
 ( SELECT 
   FROM posts AS p
   WHERE p.id_user=4
   ORDER BY p.date DESC 
   LIMIT 8, 999999999
 ) q
JOIN users u ON u.id_user=q.id_user
WHERE u.id_user=4
ORDER id_post ASC
```

And your current query doesn't need to join to users, you don't access any column from that table (but this was probably a stripped down version)

Comment: Yeahm thank you, it works, but explain me this `999999999`?

Comment: @joe: It's an arbitrary large number, larger than the possible number of posts of a user :-)